# Is there a way to retrieve final rendered pixel values of a webpage?

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm looking to see if I can iterate through the final "rendered webpage" pixel values generated by a browser like you could for an image or video.

I looked into CSS custom filters but apparently, for security reasons, you cannot retrieve individual pixel values for a page that way.

How can you find the final pixel version of a webpage rendered by a browser?

Comment: You can use a browser extension or code your own, it's very very simple. Or you can go deeper and use browser automation APIs like puppeteer or selenium. Let me know which one you prefer and I'll answer it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `html2canvas` to create a screentshot of the webpage and using `context.getImageData()` to get pixel.